# HTML5 canvas. Get points from path. beginPath / ClosePath

Tags: path, html5-canvas

Is there a way to get the points of a path created with beginPath-closePath, as XY coordinates?
Something like `Context.getPath -> Array of(x,y)`.

As the path is implemented in real code it would be way faster, than using a bezier function written in javascript.

Comment: what is it you are trying to achieve by having the x/y coords? There may be a simpler method. Remember x/y coordinates of a vector are dependent on its scale.

Answer (score 0):

There is no trivial way to do what you are suggesting. You'll likely need to come up with some kind of a solution of your own. If you can describe your problem better, we'll probably be able to provide you something more concrete.

At the worst case you'll need to implement the bezier algo yourself and accumulate the data you'll need. Alternatively you could render using the native method and then redo the math without rendering to get the data you are after (might be faster even, not sure).